# Inserting item in ListView in between existing items in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I understand how to implement list adapters, but I need something which can't be done with regular adapters I think. My needs are based on the following scenario.

- I query several remote websites for RSS and Atom feeds
- The feeds are merged into one feed using Rome and ordered by date, descending
- The data is then presented by a `ListView`, using a custom `BaseAdapter`
- I store the latest merged feed data so I have something to show after application restart
- Sometimes a feed is or has been unreachable. Upon getting new data I might retrieve  entries from this feed that are actually older then my existing locally stored data.
- I need to insert these feed entries in between the existing items in my `ListView`, without touching the `View`'s of the newer items (above them) in the `ListView`.

Basically I am looking for a `insert()` function instead of a `add()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ArrayAdapter<>` as your adapter class, you have a method for [`insert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29)

Comment: I didn't know that. Sadly I am required to use `BaseAdapter`

Comment: well, `ArrayAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter` ofcourse, so I think I will get this working with some tinkering. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need change the "container" of your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged().

If you use a ArrayAdapter, insert the data in the correct position. If you use CursorAdapter, you should make the query using "order by".